# switch case that loads queue function

Tags: jquery, queue, switch-statement

New to the programming world.  What I think is logical doesn't work.

```
  $("button").click(function(e) {
    var value;
    switch ($("button").index(this)) {
    case 0 :
    value = $("div").queue(function(next){
    $("div").load("page01.php #01");
    next();
    $("div").load("page02.php #01");
    next();
    $("div").load("page03.php #01");
    };
```

Why does this not work? If I have a single load it works fine, however I don't understand why this function does not get triggered.  I want the divs to replace each other

Comment: please define "does not work". what is `next()`? which function does not get triggered? what does it mean for divs to replace each other?

Comment: It does not work means nothing gets loaded to div. If case 0 is clicked, then I would like page01,next().delay,page02, next().delay, final page03

Comment: to implement delays you will need to use timers.

Comment: delay is not the main concern as much as the .queue function being fired off

Comment: when the click handler is invoked, what does `$("button").index(this)` return?

Comment: .index this is button clicked. When i call an alert it returns [object HTMLElement]

Comment: Well, for one thing, this snippet is not valid JavaScript. You're missing the closing `})` for both callback definitions.

Comment: Mr Lundberg you are right I did not close }), however now it goes to last page without loading first 2.

Comment: why have a switch statement with only one case?